# Why isn't this query returning an object?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am learning PHP and MySQL from 'PHP and MySQL web dev'. Currently I am finding difficulties in displaying results from database. Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <?php
        $searchtype = $_POST['searchtype'];
        $seachterm = trim($_POST['searchterm']);

        if(!$searchtype || !$seachterm){
            echo "You did not enter all the details. Bye";
            exit;
        }

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
            $seachterm = addslashes($seachterm);
        }

        @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Sorry Could not connect to db";
            exit;
        }

        $query = "select * from books where".$searchtype."like '%".$seachterm."%'";

        $result = $db -> query($query);

        $num_of_results = $result->num_rows; // Line 47

        echo "Num of books found is ".$num_of_results." ";

        for($i = 0; $i < $num_of_results; $i++){
            $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
            echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
            echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
            echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['author']);
            echo "<br />ISBN: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
            echo "<br />Price: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['price']);
            echo "</p>";
        }

        $result->free();
        $db -> close();
    ?>
</body>
```

When I run the above code, this is the error i get.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/php_crash/phptomysql/connect.php on line 47
Num of books found is
Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/php_crash/phptomysql/connect.php on line 64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably an error in your SQL query and `$result` is `false` instead of the result object.

I think it's probably because you're missing some spaces in the query. This line:

```
$query = "select * from books where".$searchtype."like '%".$seachterm."%'";
```

should be something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE '" .$searchtype. "' LIKE '%".$seachterm."%'";
```

It would help if we knew the values of:

```
$_POST['searchtype'];
$_POST['searchterm'];
```

Comment: Oh so stupid of me. Thanks a lot. Got It. MySQL needs spaces between its keywords and variable strings. Probably it was a typo. Anyways thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking to make sure that `$result` is what you think it is. It's very likely that something went wrong with your query, and the return value of `$db->query()` is `false`. It's a good idea to check for that to make sure your query actually worked.

Try using this code:

```
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result === false) {
        // Query failed - we can't continue
        die('My query failed, I want to be a teapot instead.');
}

// Now it's safe to operate on $result, deal with a successful query, but no results
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
       echo 'no results found.';
       // display any other output, search again?
       exit;
}

// At this point you have results to display
```

Now, as to why your query is failing, take a look at this part closely:

```
"select * from books where".$searchtype."like '%"
```

You need some spaces. If `$searchtype` was 'foo', your query would actually expand to:

```
 select * from books wherefoolike
```

Try instead:

```
"select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%"
```

Notice the space after 'where' and before 'like'? That should probably fix it.

I'm not going to harp too much about making sure your query is properly prepared for safety, your book should go into that - but do keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I will implement these best practices from now.